# Phalcon model hasManyToMany relation with additional condition

Tags: model, phalcon

Is there an option to add additional conditions to Phalcon wizard function hasManyToMany? I've checked the [phalcon docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#defining-relationships) but they do not list all possible options for hasManyToMany (alias and foreginKey are only listed). 
If this cannot be done with hasManyToMany is there any other Phalcon option available - eg. Retrieve all and then filter on some model load event?

Simple example:
I have 3 tables Group, Relation and User, and would like use Relation table to create two properties in User model - active_groups and inactive_groups.

Code:

```
class GroupModel extends Model {
    public $id;    
    public $name;
}

class RelationModel extends Model {
    public $id;    
    public $related_id_one;
    public $related_id_two;
    public $active;
}

class UserModel extends Model {

    public function initialize() {

        $this->hasManyToMany(
            "id",
            "RelationModel",
            "related_id_one",
            "related_id_two",
            "GroupModel",
            "id",
            array(  'alias' => 'active_groups', 
                    'conditions' => 'RelationModel.active = true')
        );

        $this->hasManyToMany(
            "id",
            "RelationModel",
            "related_id_one",
            "related_id_two",
            "GroupModel",
            "id",
            array(  'alias' => 'inactive_groups', 
                    'conditions' => 'RelationModel.active = false')
        );
    }
}
```

Tnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this instead. BTW not entirely sure if this code runs properly but you get the idea hopefully.

I don't know if phalcon has a conditions / where option or not

```
class GroupModel extends Model {
    public $id;    
    public $name;
}

class RelationModel extends Model {
    public $id;    
    public $related_id_one;
    public $related_id_two;
    public $active;
}

class UserModel extends Model {

    public function initialize() {

        $this->hasManyToMany(
            "id",
            "RelationModel",
            "related_id_one",
            "related_id_two",
            "GroupModel",
            "id",
            array(  'alias' => 'groups')
        );

    }

    public function getActiveGroups() {
      return $this->getGroups('RelationModel.active = true');
    }

    public function getInactiveGroups() {
      return $this->getGroups('RelationModel.inactive = false');
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for the reply. In the end we implemented this solution...although condition in hasManyToMany would be more cool